# Flagging word/paragraph/page on a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

I am creating an eReader application for iPad. I have a series of local XHTML files that I will be displaying on a UIWebView. These XHTML Files will be the chapters of a book and will have the functionality of **bookmarking** for the reader. A reader should be able to bookmark a word,paragraph or page on that webview by clicking (or any other gesture that can be communicated to the user) that particular piece of text and a bookmark icon image should appear on that line of text (or after that).

An extended functionality of this bookmark would be that this bookmark image would be clickable and user can then navigate to discussions etc but that should be easy enough once I am able to put the bookmark icon image on the text that was selected.

I have thought of a few approaches but none of those seem to be possible on the UIWebView. I am new to iPhone programming too. Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do these job with JavaScript. If these XHTML files are not owned by you, you can use `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script` method of `UIWebView` to load external scripts.